# No R, Como calcular a média de uma coluna com base em critério em outra coluna?

Tags: r, static

Tenho duas colunas (A e B) quero calcular a média da coluna A para os elementos correspondentes apenas para os que na coluna B forem maior que 10 por exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando é data.frame, e tenho de tirar médias de varias colunas, eu uso o código `colMeans` e dentro da função coloco tipo: `colMeans(dados[dados$coluna1=="A" & dados$coluna2=="0.01",])` normalmente ele irá obter as médias por colunas dos dados que atendam a este critério só ressalvo que na parte **,]** depois desta **virgula** você não está discriminando quais colunas entram no calculo por isso irá se realizar com todas, o problema é quando nas colunas tem caracteres ("A","NOME") pois o código costuma não realizar o calculo de médias com fatores, para isso voce pode simplesmente concatenar os respectivos números das colunas as quais você deseja os resultados. Ex: `nova.tabela.contendo.as.médias<-colMeans(dados[dados$coluna1=="A" & dados$coluna2=="0.01",c(4,1,3,2,5,7)])`,

Answer (score 6):

É um problema de seleção de linhas de uma data frame por uma condição lógica:

```
set.seed(6480)    # Para ter resultados reprodutíveis

n <- 50
dados <- data.frame(A = runif(n, 0, 100), B = runif(n, 0, 40))

mean(dados[dados$B > 10, "A"])    # índice lógico
#[1] 51.62713

mean(dados$A[dados$B > 10])       # equivalente
#[1] 51.62713
```

Mas se a coluna `B` tiver valores `NA` o índice lógico não resulta, temos que usar `which`.

```
is.na(dados$B) <- sample(n, 10)        # fazer alguns B iguais a NA

mean(dados$A[dados$B > 10])            # veja o que dados$B > 10 dá
#[1] NA

mean(dados$A[which(dados$B > 10)])
#[1] 52.17357
```

**EDIÇÃO.**

Como o Flávio Silva diz em comentário, também se pode usar o argumento `na.rm`.

```
mean(dados$A[dados$B > 10], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 52.17357
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: Na função `mean(dados$A[dados$B > 10])`, acrescentar o `na.rm = T` não seria o suficiente, ficando `mean(dados$A[dados$B > 10], na.rm = T)`?

Comment: @FlavioSilva Certo, obrigado pela sugestão, também dá. Mas o problema a que eu me estava a referir é diferente. Quando um índce lógico tem valores `NA` deve-se usar `which`. Vou editar a resposta com a sua sugestão.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Eu perguntei mais pelo fato de buscar entender a diferença entre o `na.rm` e quando usar o `which`